# View not drawn correctly when switching views

Tags: iphone, xcode

My app consists of 3 views.  I've defined 3 helper methods in the `AppDelegate` to switch between each view (so that each view can call the other), which look like this:

```
-(IBAction)goToView1 {
    if ( view1 == nil )
    {
        View1 *thisView = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
        view1 = thisView;
    }

    for (UIView *view in window.subviews)
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    [window addSubview:view1.view]; 
}
```

If the user wants to switch to another view, I tie a button to an `IBAction` defined in the view's controller:

```
-(IBAction)goToOtherView:(id)sender {
    ViewSwitcherAppDelegate *root = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];   
    [root goToView1];
}
```

This all works fine for switching views, but when the view is drawn it is displays incorrectly, like it is ignoring the status bar:

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_nbwj7pSrW10/SkcGEZ3XH0I/AAAAAAAABMs/nAkkja27e8I/s576/ViewSwitchingProblem.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_nbwj7pSrW10/SkcGEZ3XH0I/AAAAAAAABMs/nAkkja27e8I/s576/ViewSwitchingProblem.png)

What am I doing wrong?

It renders fine when the app starts up, so I suspect there's something wrong in the way I am adding the subview to the window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you set the views' frame property? If so, can you show us the code?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The views were created using the defaults.
Here's a sample project that exhibits the same behaviour (using SDK 3.0):
http://files.getdropbox.com/u/361159/ViewSwitcher.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the view's controller to display it, you have to adjust the view's frame yourself. You have to set its origin to {0, 20} to take the space for the status bar into account.

But you'd be better off to use the UIViewController and push this on the UINavigationController. [See the docs.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllers/UsingViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH5-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for that - I've taken your advice and refactored the design to use a UINavigationController instead.